# Isolating partial string and deleting any cell containing it

Tags: excel, vba

Excuse my question, I know it pedestrian, however I have very little experience with VBA.

I am looking to isolate the "Less than" character within a series of spreadsheets, and then delete those cells while leaving the row intact. I can't seem to find a solution, albeit Im sure it's a simple one.

I have tried the following,

```
Sub FindandDeleteLessThan
Dim myRange As Range
        Dim iCell As Range
        Dim myValue As String
        Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:K48")
        myValue = "<"
        For Each iCell In myRange
          If iCell.Value = myValue Then iCell.Clear
       Next iCell
end sub
```

However it seems that because the cells that contain the character also contain other values my loop wont identify them.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `iCell.Value Like "*" & myValue & "*"`

Comment: `If InStr( iCell.Value, myValue) > 0 Then`

Comment: `InStr` has better performance..

Comment: Outstanding! Thanks everyone. Worked like a charm.

Comment: The first example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.findnext) is pretty much what you are looking for and saves you looping through all cells in your range

Answer (score 0):

You won't need any looping, just use a wildcard in a `Range.Replace`:

```
Sub FindandDeleteLessThan
    Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:K48")
    myRange.Replace "*<*", ""
End sub
```